# How to properly make custom filter in django framework?

Tags: python, django, django-template-filters

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('menu/create_minimenu.html', takes_context = True)
def minimenu(context):
....
....
@register.inclusion_tag('menu/create_topmenu.html', takes_context = True)
def topmenu(context):
....
....
@register.filter(name = 'commatodot')
def commatodot(value, arg):
    return str(value).replace(",", '.')
commatodot.isSafe = True
```

template.html

```
...
initGeolocation2({{ place.longitude|commatodot }}, {{ place.latitude|commatodot }}, "MAIN");
...
```

Error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /places/3/

Invalid filter: 'commatodot'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/places/3/
Django Version:     1.2.4
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    

Invalid filter: 'commatodot'
```

This tags from file work well, but the filter not. But I don't know why...

Answer (score 26):

1. Did you put the file with the filters inside a `templatetags` module in your app? I.e., you should have a structure like:

```
project/
  my_app/
    templatetags/
      __init__.py    # Important! It makes templatetags a module. You can put your filters here, or in another file.
      apptags.py     # Or just put them in __init__.py
```

2. Did you include the tags? You need something like

```
{% load apptags %}
```

in your template.

Comment: It is done... And templatetags, and "include". But not solve my problem and how I wrote my custom tags work.

Comment: You don't `include` a tag library, you `load` it: `{% load apptags %}`

Comment: @mipadi thx for the `templatetags` tip. However I keep getting the same error message, seems to me Django isn't looking for my_app.templatetags although I have myapp listed in INSTALLED_APPS. What do you suggest? Thx

Comment: @DiAlex tip is important. Add the app position to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Answer (score 9):

For create your custom filter in django follow these steps

1). Create a **template_tags folder** in your app.

2). Add/Copy a `__init__.py` file in this folder for ensure that this is a python folder.

3). Add **your_custom_filter_name.py** file look like:

> `from django import template
>   register = template.Library()`
>
> `@register.filter(name = 'get_class')
>   '''A filter for get class name of object.'''
>   def get_class(value):
>       return value.__class__.__name__`

4). To load this filter add this at top 
**{% load your_custom_filter_name %}**
in html template . 
.

5). **Restart your server** and enjoy :)

And for **more info** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/ follow this link

Comment: Looks like the file name must be custom_filter and we can't change it to whatever we want. Can we?

Comment: You can change it, sorry for this :).

Comment: I did not restart the server before. You're right, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Very important the remark of restarting the server, the error was driving me crazy.

Comment: `s/template_tags/templatetags/`