# "TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter:"; custom django template filter based on django docs broken, but template tags working

Tags: python, django, templates, django-template-filters

I have a template filter based on the django docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/. For the life of me I can't see any difference in my usage and theirs, and am slowly going insane. I have a working tag I got on a forum as such:

myproject/index/templatetags/add_get_parameter.py:

```
from django.template import Library, Node, resolve_variable

register = Library()

class AddGetParameter(Node):
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values

    def render(self, context):
        req = resolve_variable('request', context)
        params = req.GET.copy()
        for key, value in self.values.items():
            params[key] = value.resolve(context)
        return '?%s' %  params.urlencode()

@register.tag
def add_get(parser, token):
    pairs = token.split_contents()[1:]
    values = {}

    for pair in pairs:
        s = pair.split('=', 1)
        values[s[0]] = parser.compile_filter(s[1])
    return AddGetParameter(values)
```

This one, `add_get` on lines 8-9, works, whereas `shorten_title` on line 4 doesn't work:

myproject/templates/index/silo.html:

```
{% load bootstrap add_get_parameter extras %}



 ...other stuff...

{% for article in articles %}
        <div  class="col-md-4 article-link">
            <div class="panel panel-default hover">
                <div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="url-link">{{ article.title|shorten_title }}</h4></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>&nbsp;<span class="url-text">{{ article.url }}</span></p>
                    <a href="{% url 'index:edit-article' article.id %}"><div class="article_button">Edit</div></a>
                    <a href="{% add_get archive=article.id %}"><div class="article_button"><p>Archive</p></div></a>
                    <a href="{% add_get delete=article.id %}"><div class="article_button">Delete</div></a>
                    <div style="margin-top:8px;">
                        {% for tag in article.tags.all %}
                            <p class="tag">{{ tag.name }}</p>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Here's the villian:

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.filter
def shorten_title(title):
    length = len(title)
    new = title
    if length > 65:
        new = title[0:65] + "..."
    return new
register.filter('shorten_title', shorten_title)
```

He's been so rude I double registered him, just to see what happens (he doesn't work registered once as a decorator or afterward, and doesn't work registered twice).

`{{ article.title }}` works, but `{{ article.title|shorten_title }}` breaks the page with:

```
django.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError
TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter: 'shorten_title'
```

'Index' is definitely registered and working, and the page works when I delete the filter from that article.title tag.

Usually when I get a stubborn error I missed something small, but following the docs word for word has me baffled (I've written several working filters before). Is this filter bad, or is there maybe something else in my page that causes the issue? Thanks

Comment: So where is that `shorten_title` code? What file? Are you importing that file in the template? (Also note you shouldn't use *both* the decorator and the direct `register.filter(..)` call: choose one or the other.)

Comment: shorten title was in extras.py. I literally cut and pasted the code from there into a new file with no tags (only this one filter), and now it works. could it have been one of those weird pyc things where you gotta delete all your pyc, or maybe template tags and filters shouldn't be in the same file? following the django examples twice, one day works and one day it doesn't is baffling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you import the file with `register.filter('shorten_title', shorten_title)` before you render the template. Since that call happens outside of any functions it is run when you import the module. This has the side effect of registering it so that it will be available in your templates afterwards.

Comment: where at? I currently have it as listed above, with `register.filter('shorten_title', shorten_title)` right below the filter in the same file (index/templatetags/extras.py)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You just need to import that entire module  that has that line before using the filter. If that file is never imported then the filter is never registered.

Comment: in the view? Like `from index.templatetags import extras`? I load extras in the template as above in the .html file

Comment: In the view or the template, I think. Now that I see `{% load bootstrap add_get_parameter extras %}`, something very similar should work for shorten_title. I am not quite sure what the best way in Django is because I am answering this question based on having a similar experience with Flask.

Comment: add_get_parameter  and extras are the names of the file. I just loaded add_get_parameter and called add_get, but this doesn't work for the other file

Comment: I am at a lose at the moment. Here is a related question that you can look over to see if you missed anything (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938303/how-to-properly-make-custom-filter-in-django-framework), but at the moment I don't see any problem with your code.

Comment: there's just always somethin with django. think it's time to learn rails

Comment: is flask better? if I had a nickel for every django doc example followed to a T that didn't work, I'd have about 500 bucks

Comment: I can't make an informed comparison, but Flask is lightweight and I like it. If you google for flask, it won't take you long to get started with it and see if you like it too because the documentation is pretty good.

Comment: I just glanced at Flask, it looks interesting. A few hundred times of following the django docs exactly and it not working can get exhausting lol